# Looking for a good method for tuning parameters in Hough Guil Detection

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, hough-transform

I am struggling to tune a Hough Guil detector in opencv (using java). I cannot find very much guidance on how to do so as the tutorials don't explain many of the parameters involved. Here is my detector setup:

```
public class TemplateHoughGuilDetector {
    public static PositionVector runHoughGuilDetection(Mat template, Mat blurred) {
        var houghDetector = Imgproc.createGeneralizedHoughGuil();
        houghDetector.setLevels(1500);
        houghDetector.setScaleThresh(200);
        houghDetector.setPosThresh(200);
        houghDetector.setAngleThresh(1000);
        houghDetector.setDp(15);
        houghDetector.setMinDist(.1);
        houghDetector.setAngleStep(.1);
        houghDetector.setAngleEpsilon(1);
        houghDetector.setMinAngle(0);
        houghDetector.setMaxAngle(360);
        houghDetector.setMinScale(.99);
        houghDetector.setMaxScale(1.01);
        houghDetector.setScaleStep(.01);
        houghDetector.setXi(90.0);


        PositionVector bestVoted = mostLikelyHoughDetectionWithScaleTolerance(template, blurred, houghDetector);
        return bestVoted;
    }

    private static PositionVector mostLikelyHoughDetectionWithScaleTolerance(Mat template, Mat blurred, GeneralizedHough houghDetector) {
        houghDetector.setTemplate(template);
        var positions = new Mat();
        var votes = new Mat();

        houghDetector.detect(blurred, positions, votes);

        var positionVectors = new ArrayList<PositionVector>();
        for(int i = 0; i < positions.width(); i++) {
            var posData = positions.get(0, i);
            var voteData = votes.get(0, i);
            positionVectors.add(new PositionVector(posData[0], posData[1], posData[2], posData[3], voteData[0], voteData[1], voteData[2]));
        }

        final double maxPosVote = positionVectors.stream().map(PositionVector::posVotes).max(Double::compareTo).orElse(1.0);
        final double maxRotVote = positionVectors.stream().map(PositionVector::rotVotes).max(Double::compareTo).orElse(1.0);
        final double maxScaleVote = positionVectors.stream().map(PositionVector::scaleVotes).max(Double::compareTo).orElse(1.0);
        var bestScore = positionVectors.stream().map(v -> v.voteMagSqr(maxPosVote, maxRotVote, maxScaleVote)).max(Double::compareTo);

        MatOfPoint bestVoted = null;
        var output = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(blurred, output, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        var contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        for (PositionVector v:positionVectors) {
            var rect = new RotatedRect(new Point(v.x(), v.y()), new Size(499, 499), v.rotation());
            var points = new Point[4];
            rect.points(points);
            final var contour = new MatOfPoint(points);

            if(v.voteMagSqr(maxPosVote, maxRotVote, maxScaleVote) == bestScore.get()) {
                bestVoted = contour;
            }

            contours.add(contour);
        }

        var drawMe = ContourOntoImage.createImageWithContours(output, contours, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
        if(bestVoted != null) {
            drawMe = ContourOntoImage.createImageWithContours(drawMe, List.of(bestVoted), new Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 255.0), 2);
        }
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("test_contours.png", drawMe);

        return positionVectors.stream().filter(pv -> pv.voteMagSqr(maxPosVote, maxRotVote, maxScaleVote) == bestScore.get()).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

}
```

and I call it from this test:

```
    @Test
    public void perfectSquareRotNotScaledGuil() {
        loadLocally();
        Mat template = makeRectangularGrayBigTemplate();

        Mat blurred = makeRotatedBlurredRectangularGrayImage();

        PositionVector bestVoted = TemplateHoughGuilDetector.runHoughGuilDetection(template, blurred);

        var loc = new Point(bestVoted.x(), bestVoted.y());
        var rot = bestVoted.rotation();
        var scale = bestVoted.scale();

        assertThat(loc, is(closeToPoint(new Point(500, 500)).toWithin(1e-7)));
        assertThat(rot, is(closeTo(5.0, 1.0)));
        assertThat(scale, is(equalTo(1.0)));
    }

    private static Mat makeRotatedBlurredRectangularGrayImage() {
        Mat image = makeRotatedRectangularGrayImage();
        var blurred = new Mat();
        Imgproc.blur(image, blurred, new Size(3,3));
        return blurred;
    }

    private static Mat makeRectangularGrayBigTemplate() {
        var template = new Mat(501, 501, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255));
        Imgproc.rectangle(template, new Point(1, 1), new Point(499, 499), new Scalar(0), Imgproc.FILLED);
        return template;
    }

    private static Mat makeRotatedRectangularGrayImage() {
        var image = new Mat(1000, 1000, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255));
        var rectangle = new RotatedRect(new Point(500, 500), new Size(499.0, 499.0), 5);
        var vertices = new Point[4];
        rectangle.points(vertices);
        var matOfPoints = new MatOfPoint(vertices);
        Imgproc.fillConvexPoly(image, matOfPoints, new Scalar(0));
        return image;
    }
```

I get the following image:

[image: contours including the one with the bust normalized scores]

and the template looks like this:

[image: template]

So what I've been able to determine so far is:

- Levels didn't seem to do much
- the thresholds do allow more worse detections but I cannot seem to get an accurate detection.
- DP I cannot find a description of anywhere but does have an affect on how many bad detections I get. I've run it from 1 to 250 and by 250 I just get 2 detections, one at 0 degrees and one at twice the angle it should be
- MinDist seems to increase the density of the detections in position, makes sense
- angle step doesn't seem to get me the right angles
- angle epsilon didn't do it..
- min and max angle make sense
- min scale and max scale make sense
- scale step makes sense
- if I change Xi from 90.0 to 10.0 or even 45.0 it simply doesn't find anything. It says angle between features when I look it up but does that mean from the center of the object, one edge?

So does anyone know how to get that test to find the accurate angle and position? Or has anyone found a good description of these parameters?

===== EDIT =====

In case I am just using the wrong algorithm, the sort of detection I am trying to do is find objects like the panel with the circle and cross in an image:

[image: parts on bed]

using the dxf that looks like:

[image: dxf]

pardon the darkness of the dxf image

I am able to successfully detect it based on outlines but am working on some advances that require I not use the outline so I can find parts accurately based on the cutouts when the outlines are not accurate.

Comment: Wow, that functionality is really poorly documented… I guess you’ll have to read the code to figure out what those parameters do. :(

Comment: also not much work on this stuff. nobody's been _really_ touching it for a decade. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commits/726ba0210e1592606ccb8843fb092504ca787096/modules/imgproc/src/generalized_hough.cpp I would *not* put my trust in the implementation, or the algorithms. it's still just Hough transform. old ideas.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what would be the current ideas then? Machine learning needs large amounts of data to train, but I need to find things based on a shape that is arbitrary each time so as far as I know this is still the state of the art.

Comment: please show examples of such shapes then. don't show anything that doesn't represent the actual problem. show representative examples.

Comment: This is my simple example, and it doesn't work on the simple example. Showing more complicated shapes, which are combinations of lines and circle segments with cutouts in them, would not make the question easier to understand.

Comment: though @ChristophRackwitz if I had asked the question (which I probably should have) of whether this was the best algorithm to use, yeah more representative pictures would have been good. I'll add one.

Comment: for that "panel with a hole and a cross cut", generalized Hough is a reasonable approach but I can't predict whether it can work well. -- unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't implement the "machine vision" type of algorithms you can find in *commercial machine vision* software packages (industry, automated optical inspection). those algorithms might still have patents on them.

Comment: commercial MV approaches extract "well-defined" features from the template. those would be corners, not edges, because any point on an edge can just slide around on the edge and still "match" that edge (degrees of freedom). I believe those implementations also don't work with an accumulator array but perhaps with point sets that are clustered. less data, less work to do. they also thoroughly filter outliers (check for a good match along the whole contour), very likely employ multiple iterations to locate the instance precisely, once it was found.

Comment: alright, I'll revise and stick to what I always say: Hough is never a reasonable approach. even the low-dimensional variants (circle, line) take a lot of time and this here, Hough-Guil, take AGES to find anything. that's not reasonable. that's useless. for the official OpenCV example, I'm having to wait two minutes for the detection.

Comment: So these sort of commercial algorithms you mention, I made an attempt at doing something like that, but the matching of feature to feature looking at all combinations I believe is an O(n^3) sort of operation. It was waaay slower than hough-guil and crashed the computer over a relatively small number of features.  We've managed a convolution-based approach but had to use GPUs to get it to run in a decent time. 

So how does a person find these commercial algorithms or are they simply not available if you aren't a part of the organization?

Comment: patents are public. you could get the names of the biggest companies in that space, then look up patents involving those companies, but now your brain is legally "tainted by the knowledge" and if you ever implement any of that, even if you forgot that you read the patents, and you have no idea that you follow the patents, then you're gonna have to pay... or wait for patent expiration.

Comment: a small set of good features usually improves the situation (see also: SIFT). Hough does the opposite, uses shit features and scatters them across the accumulator. if you claim an O(n^3) situation even with few good features, then that strikes me as in need of better algorithms, meaning you _should not_ just do a cartesian product of whatever. -- I've seen building blocks of the commercial approaches. they chop contours up into recognizable pieces like "straight" and "arc". you could then have features like `straight(50), arc(+90,r=5), straight(200)` and match on those phrases